# How to send s/mime messages through Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I searched the documentations. It appears that Microsoft Graph API supports downloading S/MIME messages, but not sending S/MIME messages. Could anyone confirm if this is supported?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, You are right. Microsoft does not support sending messages. You can vote here for this. https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/39762832-provide-functionality-to-create-message-using-mime